# hide all the images with the appropriate SRC, including some conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to hide every image in the page with a certain `src` atribute, except the images with parent `a` element which has a `href` attribute starting with `/dailyTickets/front/user.form.php` or with `/dailyTickets/front/user.php`.

I'm using this method, but it hides all the images with `src`, in the `a` test he just can't find the img to do his job

```
$('img[src=\"/dailyTickets/pics/aide.png\"]').hide();
$('img[src=\"/dailyTickets/pics/aide.png\"]').parent('a[href^=\"/dailyTickets/front/user.form.php\"]').show();
$('img[src=\"/dailyTickets/pics/aide.png\"]').parent('a[href^=\"/dailyTickets/front/user.php\"]').show();
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: I think this sounds like a very bad way of solving what could potentially be a much simpler problem. Can you explain why you need to do this?

Comment: Also, if you have to work with the same elments a few more times, save them. No need to let jQuery search for the items every time. `var el =  $('img[src=\"/dailyTickets/pics/aide.png\"]');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is you are using show() on the parent item, not the image itself. Try something like:

```
$('a[href^=\"/dailyTickets/front/user.form.php\"]').find('img[src=\"/dailyTickets/pics/aide.png\"]').show();
```

Comment: On top of this I highly agree with @Rory McCrossan, it does look like you are over complicating things...

Comment: yes , that's it , it works perfectly  ; emmm i'm complicating things be couse i'm new in jquery ^_^ tnkkkkkkks

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is what you need :)
https://www.npmjs.com/package/location-hide

and it´s also easy to usen even if you never used node.js